Non-uniqueness of the unitary transformation
The following question has arisen in the course of a physics problem. Suppose I have two Hermitian matrices, denoted by $A$ and $B$. In the problem, I have found two distinct unitary matrices $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that
$$
A=U_1BU_1^{\dagger}=U_2BU_2^{\dagger},\quad U_1\neq U_2.
$$
I am wondering if there is a systematic way to parametrize the family of unitary matrices $\{U\}$ such that $A=UBU^{\dagger}$. As an example of what I mean, I can of course multiply any such $U$ by some complex phase $U\mapsto U e^{i\alpha}$, and $A$ will still be unitarily similar to $B$. More generally, if there were a third unitary matrix $X$ such that $[A,X]=0$, then $U\mapsto XU$ would also be an admissible unitary transform. Any help would be appreciated!

Let $\mathfrak U$ denote the set of all unitary $U$ such that $A = U B U^\dagger$. Also let $\mathfrak X$ denote the set of all unitary $X$ such that $AX = XA$. I claim that given $U \in \mathfrak U$ there is a bijective map $\mathfrak X \rightarrow \mathfrak U$ such that $X \rightarrow XU$.
Indeed, it is straightforward to check that given $U \in \mathfrak U$ and $X \in \mathfrak X$, we get $XU \in \mathfrak U$. The map $X \rightarrow XU$ is injective, since it is a multiplication with a fixed unitary matrix $U$. It remains to prove surjectivity.
Assume that $A = UBU^\dagger = U_1BU_1^\dagger$. Then $A U_1 U^\dagger = U_1 U^\dagger A$. Thus, $X = U_1 U^\dagger$ commutes with $A$. Moreover, $X$ is unitary and $U_1 = X U$.
This can be put in a more general mathematical picture that explains the role of the arbitrary chosen $U \in \mathfrak U$. It can be easily seen that $\mathfrak X$ is a group wrt multiplication of matrices. What we actually proved is that $\mathfrak X$ is acting on $\mathfrak U$ by left multiplication and this action is free and transitive. In this case $\mathfrak U$ is the only orbit of this action and, since $\mathfrak X$ acts without fixed points, any choice of $U \in \mathfrak U$ leads to a bijective correspondence between $\mathfrak X$ and $\mathfrak U$.

Interesting, thank you! Suppose we only knew one $U_1\in\mathfrak{U}$, but we could determine every $X\in\mathfrak{X}$ such that $[A,X]=0$. Is it possible to generate the set $\mathfrak{U}$ by acting each $X$ on $U_1$?

@CW279 Yes, when X ranges over $\mathfrak X$ the matrices $XU_1$ form exactly the set $\mathfrak U$.

Much appreciated, thank you!
